# cookies not shown on developer tools but shown on popup of padlock icon

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser, setcookie, developer-tools

Some cookies are not seen in chrome developer tools, but are listed under cookies in the popup that appears on clicking the padlock icon (the secure lock icon near the url in browser). Are these cookies actually used by the site? Is there any difference between the cookies shown in developer tools and this? Why are they not listed in developer tools?

Comment: Is this specific to Chrome, Firefox, some other browser?

Comment: @Evert Checked in chrome and safari. Some cookies are not shown in safari developer tool as well, but found cookie listing feature in padlock icon popup in chrome only.

Answer (score 0):

The cookies under the padlock are informative of what cookies could be used on the site. The cookies located under chrome dev tools are the ones that are actually set on your browser.